# Elixir and Haskell interoperability

Tags: haskell, elixir, interop, erlang-otp

As a platform for handling concurrent problems, Elixir/OTP seems to be the best suited solution.

When writing an application with a web interface, consider the case in which I want to reason about, and decouple, the application logic using another functional language - namely haskell (due to benefits like its advanced detection of errors at compile time, static typing, etc). I would then handle concurrency using `GenServer`s, and attach a web interface using `Phoenix.Channel`s.

Is this setup even possible using `NIF`s? Also, would true concurrency be maintained? I'm not sure that I'm following the correct line of reasoning here, but would a new haskell process be able to be spawned in line with `GenServer` demands, and would the two be able communicate efficiently?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but as written the question seems rather unclear to me. I can't tell what architecture you're envisioning here. Though tbh even if I could I'm not sure this question is on-topic for SO. This seems to be mostly about software engineering rather than programming per se; The question about concurrency might be answerable if you go into more detail on that, the rest I'm not so sure about.

Comment: `NIF`s are Elixir/Erlang mechanisms for interoperability with external programs. So the architecture here would be two Elixir `Application`s - a Phoenix `Application` for the `Phoenix.Channel` web interface, and a second that would handle the Haskell interop (this would be loaded into the first as a dependency). The Haskell application would then communicate w. Elixir via `NIF`s. OTP refers to a set of Elixir `Behaviour`s (including `GenServer`) that leverage the `BEAM` to handle concurrency.

Comment: _Biased and opinionated:_ choosing Haskell because of hype around to drastically increase the complexity does not sound reasonable enough. `NIF` will ruin all your type safety (even if it was a goodness) and the number of pitfalls and rakes you are going to step on would make the whole development process a disaster (besides that overcomplicated interoperation would bring more issues than could ever happen in plain old good elixir application.)

Comment: "Would true concurrency be maintained?" is not something which can be answered easily.  It's not dependent on Haskell and Elixir solely but much more dependent on how the code is written.

Comment: Consider https://github.com/jeremyjh/dialyxir for type-related error detection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This setup is certainly possible using NIFs and GHC's FFI with a small amount of boilerplate [written in C](https://wiki.haskell.org/Calling_Haskell_from_C). But [NIFs are best used for short synchronous computations with no side effects](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/nif.html) and I get the feeling that that isn't what these operations are.

You'd probably be better off with [C Nodes](http://erlang.org/doc/tutorial/cnode.html) for the Haskell parts of the application. Most of the documentation you'll find for that will be for Erlang and not Elixir, but given Elixir's easy interop with Erlang, it should be pretty straight forward (someone's [even written an example](https://github.com/remiq/elixir-cnode-example/blob/master/src/complex.ex)). Most of the hard work will be to do with writing a Haskell "C Node", for which a cursory glance at hackage and github turns up nothing.